# Mozilla engine simple questions

Tags: html-parsing, webbrowser-control, mozilla, gecko

Three questions about the Mozilla engine (Gecko/XUL):

1. Is it possible to use its HTML parser in my C/C++ application (no any GUI, etc)?
2. Can I embed the browser (only the page output without any menu, windows, etc) into my application like a control (like it does IE ActiveX, but I need a cross-platfromed solution)?
3. Is it possible to customize page output (e.g. add some grid lines)?

May be it's better to pick some other engine? Can any body make me a hint this case?

Thank you very much!

Comment: protip: In general, try to avoid multiple questions in one question body

Comment: Sure, sorry. It's my first time here :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes but probably not quite the way you think. Gecko currently uses the [HTML5 parser from validator.nu](http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/) (translated from Java to C++ automatically). You can use the same parser in your application.
2. You can embed XULRunner. However, it is everything but simple and not exactly well-documented - WebKit should be easier to embed.
3. If you embed XULRunner you mean? Sure, you can set up user styles via [nsIStyleSheetService.loadAndRegisterSheet()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIStyleSheetService#loadAndRegisterSheet%28%29) for example.